# When the program loops it prints the line "Enter your name (first and last): " twice?

Tags: java

So in the program I ask the user whether they want to rerun the program but when it does it prints the line  "Enter your name," followed by a space, twice. Can someone please help me find the cause of this? It doesn't happen when you run it the first time by the way.

```
import java.util.Scanner;  
public class PirateName                                         
{                                                                
    static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); 
    static String[]firstNames = {"Captain", "Dirty", "Squidlips", "Bowman", "Buccaneer",       
        "Two toes", "Sharkbait", "Old", "Peg Leg", "Fluffbucket",       
         "Scallywag", "Bucko", "Deadman", "Matey", "Jolly",       
         "Stinky", "Bloody", "Miss", "Mad", "Red", "Lady",       
          "Shipwreck", "Rapscallion", "Dagger", "Landlubber", "Freebooter"};       


    static String[]secondNames =        
    {"Creeper","Jim","Storm","John","George","Money","Rat","Jack","Legs",      
    "Head","Cackle","Patch","Bones","Plank","Greedy","Mama","Spike","Squiffy",      
    "Gold","Yellow","Felony","Eddie","Bay","Thomas","Spot","Sea"};      

    static String[]thirdNames =        
        {"From-the-West","Byrd","Jackson","Sparrow","Of-the-Coast","Jones","Ned-Head",      
        "Bart","O'Fish","Kidd","O'Malley","Barnacle","Holystone","Hornswaggle",      
        "McStinky","Swashbuckler","Sea-Wolf","Beard","Chumbucket","Rivers","Morgan",      
        "Tuna-Breath","Three Gates","Bailey","Of-Atlantis","Of-Dark-Water"};      

    static String[] letters = {"a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o",      
    "p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"};      

    public static void main(String[] args) {       

        System.out.println("Welcome to the pirate name generator");       
        System.out.println("");  
        boolean running = true; 
        while(running){ 
            nameGenerator(); 
        } 
    } 


    public static boolean nameGenerator()  
    {
        boolean rerun = false; 
        int x = 0;       


        System.out.println("Enter your name (first and last): ");     
        String userName = input.nextLine();      
        System.out.println("");      
        try{ 
            String first = userName.substring(0,1);   
            for (int i=0;i <= 25 ; i++)      
            {      
                if(first.equalsIgnoreCase(letters[i]))      
                {      
                    first = firstNames[i];      

                }      

            }      
            String last1 = userName.substring(userName.indexOf(' ')+1);      

            for (int i=0;i <= 25 ; i++)      
            {      
                if(last1.substring(0,1).equalsIgnoreCase(letters[i]))      
                {      
                    last1 = secondNames[i];      

                }      

            }      
            String last2 = userName.substring(userName.length() - 1);     
            for (int i=0;i <= 25 ; i++)      
            {      
                if(last2.equalsIgnoreCase(letters[i]))      
                {      
                    last2 = thirdNames[i];      

                }      

            }      
            System.out.println("Your pirate name is: ");     
            System.out.println("");     
            System.out.println(first+" "+last1+" "+last2);     
            System.out.println("");
            System.out.println("Would you like to try again? (Type 1 for yes, 2- no)");     
            int a = input.nextInt(); 

            if (a==2)     
            {     
                rerun = false;   
                System.out.println("Good Bye!"); 
                return rerun; 
            }     
            else 
            {   
                rerun = true; 
            }   

            return rerun;  
        }    
    catch (Exception e){ 
        System.out.println(" "); 
    } 
        return rerun; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it running through the whole loop a second time?

Answer (score 1):

I see at least three problems.

- At the end of the method, when you read the value of `a`, you're pulling an integer from the `Scanner`, but you're not pulling out the newline character that follows the integer.  This means that next time you call `nextLine()`, all you'll get is a blank line.  The cure for this is to add an extra `input.nextLine()` immediately after `input.nextInt()`.
- You're catching exceptions and throwing them away, without even printing their stack traces.  That means that if your program does encounter a problem, you'll never find out any information about the problem.
- You're not using the value `rerun` outside the `nameGenerator` method.  When you call it, you're checking if `running` is true, but `running` will never change, so you'll just go on calling it forever.  So you probably want to change the code that calls it to this.

  ```
  boolean shouldRun = true; 
  while (shouldRun) {
      shouldRun = nameGenerator(); 
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using the input scanner for entering both ints and strings. You should use two separate scanners, or change it so that input is brought in with .nextLine() and then changed to an integer.

The problem is you enter two characters when deciding to try again. The first is the int, the second is the  character. The second character is not an integer, so it is left in the buffer. Then when you get input a second time, you are using a scanner that already has characters in the buffer. So it processes the buffer and reads the left over  char as an empty line.

http://www.java-forums.org/new-java/24042-input-nextline.html